# how to split a text with more than one delimiter?

Tags: java, string, split

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String s=new String("f;sjdkfd:fdsfdf;df:FD::D:::F:RE:FRER:F:ER:FR:F:RF:GR:G:RG:  :P");
    String[] ss = s.split(":");

    for(String token : ss){
        System.out.println(token);
    }
}
```

using this code, I can get the token between ":". But I wan to split the text with both ":"and";" at the same time. is that possible?

Comment: You can do this using [Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use character class instead:

```
String[] ss = s.split("[:;]");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression:

```java
String[] ss = s.split("[:;]")
```

So, the code will be:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = new String("f;sjdkfd:fdsfdf;df:FD::D:::F:RE:FRER:F:ER:FR:F:RF:GR:G:RG:  :P");
    String[] ss = s.split("[:;]");

    for (String token : ss) {
        System.out.println(token);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang), specifically [this StrTokenizer constructor](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrTokenizer.html#StrTokenizer(char[], char)):

```
StrTokenizer tokenizer = new StrTokenizer("f;sjdkfd:fdsfdf;df:FD::D:::F:RE:FRER:F:ER:FR:F:RF:GR:G:RG:  :P".toCharArray(), ":");
tokenizer.next(); // will give you "f;sjdkfd", followed by fdsfdf;df, etc. with every call to .next()
```